# Tables are left-aligning in outlook

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Can't figure out why parts of my email are going outside the 600px width and then left aligning to the edge of the page.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
      <table align="center" bgcolor="#efefef" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td style="font-family:Arial; font-size:13px">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrap100pc" width="600">
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" class="padd_lr_25" style="padding: 15px 35px 25px; background-color: #F9F9FB ;" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td align="left" class="line-height-28" style="word-break:break-all; font-family: Open Sans; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #040B20; line-height: 33px; padding-bottom: 15px; word-spacing: -1px; " valign="top">
                              Coming Attractions: More Life Hubs</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: It might be because your TD's dont have a width. You can try that but the advice i'd give is to use trail an error constantly to try figure it out.  Strip it back as much as you can, and then work on the part thats misbehaving.   Its pretty much the only reliable way to work these things out with outlook.   I used to work on marketing emails, so wish you all the best in the headaches to come, its hard work but can feel pretty rewarding once you make some breakthroughs.

Comment: Many email clients default to `box-sizing: content-box` instead of `border-box`. Watch out for that.